# Index Outside Bounds of Array due to 4 digit ID

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am using VS2010 and VB.net 2.0.  I have modified code that I found online that will allow me to mass update a gridview.  The datakey for the gridview is an operator number (referenced by variable currentID), most of which are 3 digits, but a few are 4 digits.  The code works great except for when it comes to the rows with the 4 digit operator numbers.  The 4 digit operator number returns an error of Index was outside the bounds of the array when it gets to this statement:

```
Dim gvMgr_row As System.Data.DataRow = gvMgr_originalDataTable.Select(String.Format("op_num = {0}", currentID))(0)
```

I have been unable to determine why 4 digits cause an issue and would appreciate any help or advice.  All of the relevant code should be included below.

```
Protected Sub MgrUpdateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MgrUpdateButton.Click
    gvMgr_originalDataTable = CType(ViewState("gvMgr_originalValuesDataTable"), System.Data.DataTable)

    For Each r As GridViewRow In gvMgrData.Rows
        If gvMgr_IsRowModified(r) Then gvMgrData.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, False)
    Next

    ' Rebind the Grid to repopulate the original values table.
    gvMgr_tableCopied = False
    gvMgrData.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Function gvMgr_IsRowModified(ByVal r As GridViewRow) As Boolean
    Dim currentID As Integer
    Dim currentThreshold1 As String
    Dim currentPayout1 As String
    Dim currentThreshold2 As String
    Dim currentPayout2 As String
    Dim currentThreshold3 As String
    Dim currentPayout3 As String
    Dim currentThreshold4 As String
    Dim currentPayout4 As String

    currentID = Convert.ToInt32(gvMgrData.DataKeys(r.RowIndex).Value)

    currentThreshold1 = CType(r.FindControl("Threshold1TextBox"), TextBox).Text
    currentPayout1 = CType(r.FindControl("Payout1TextBox"), TextBox).Text
    currentThreshold2 = CType(r.FindControl("Threshold2TextBox"), TextBox).Text
    currentPayout2 = CType(r.FindControl("Payout2TextBox"), TextBox).Text
    currentThreshold3 = CType(r.FindControl("Threshold3TextBox"), TextBox).Text
    currentPayout3 = CType(r.FindControl("Payout3TextBox"), TextBox).Text
    currentThreshold4 = CType(r.FindControl("Threshold4TextBox"), TextBox).Text
    currentPayout4 = CType(r.FindControl("Payout4TextBox"), TextBox).Text

    Dim gvMgr_row As System.Data.DataRow = gvMgr_originalDataTable.Select(String.Format("op_num = {0}", currentID))(0)

    If Not currentThreshold1.Equals(gvMgr_row("Threshold1").ToString()) Then Return True
    If Not currentPayout1.Equals(gvMgr_row("Payout1").ToString()) Then Return True
    If Not currentThreshold2.Equals(gvMgr_row("Threshold2").ToString()) Then Return True
    If Not currentPayout2.Equals(gvMgr_row("Payout2").ToString()) Then Return True
    If Not currentThreshold3.Equals(gvMgr_row("Threshold3").ToString()) Then Return True
    If Not currentPayout3.Equals(gvMgr_row("Payout3").ToString()) Then Return True
    If Not currentThreshold4.Equals(gvMgr_row("Threshold4").ToString()) Then Return True
    If Not currentPayout4.Equals(gvMgr_row("Payout4").ToString()) Then Return True

    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: the error means there are no rows which satisfies the select criteria of `op_num = _NNNN_`. Therefore the `...)(0)` throws the exception. Are you sure there are row/s in the **gvMgr_originalDataTable** having op_num equals _NNNN_?

Comment: Yes, the op_num in questions, 2130, is listed when I view the properties of gvMgr_originalDataTable.

Comment: What is the type of op_num datacolumn (integer, string, ...)?

Comment: The database column is nvarchar

Comment: I have put a try/catch statement in place. Out of the first three rows, 2 of them have a 4 digit ID, but only one of them is caught by the catch statement.  I verified the indexes are within range on both.  I also verified the data using the visualizer.  The row index is 2 and the op_num is 2270.  I have also verified that the gvMgr_originalDataTable also has op_num of 2270.